# Calling method of running java applet (from java, c++ or others)

Tags: java, methods, applet, call

i have a question. Is it possible to call a method of Java applet which is running in browser? And if it is, how to do it? Language is not that important, (but not lower than c).

Thanks in advance, 
Marcin

Comment: what exactly do you mean by lower than C ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Oracle's tutorial on how to invoke [Java Applet method from JavaScript](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html).

Comment: Hmm, ah i didnt precise. It has to be a programming language, becouse i need to do various things before i invoke a method. Probably i can pass javaScript to browser (fe from c), but i preffer to avoid it.

Comment: *"It has to be a programming language"*  That works out well, since JS is a programming language.

Comment: Java Script is not a programming language.